# I'm trying to "draw" a circle using a span, sometimes work, sometimes doesn't

Tags: tailwind-css

This puzzles me a lot. I'm writing a Laravel application, and I want to draw a circle besides a description. The circle must be either gray or yellow depending on a condition, so my code is:

```
...
<ul>
  @foreach ($section->lessons as $lesson)
    <li class="flex items-start mb-1">
      <span class="inline-block w-4 h-4 mt-1 mr-2 {{ $lesson->complete ? 'bg-yellow-400' : 'bg-gray-500' }} rounded-full"></span>
      <a
        class="cursor-pointer"
        wire:click="changeLesson({{ $lesson }})"
        >{{ $lesson->name }}</a>
    </li>
  @endforeach
</ul>
...
```

This code works, no problem with it, but with the display. Check the `span` Tailwind classes: `"inline-block w-4 h-4 mt-1 mr-2 bg-yellow-400 }} rounded-full"`, this should draw a perfect circle (w-4 h-4) right?

Now see what it displays:

[image]

As you can see, for the one line descriptions, the circle is perfect, but for the ones that have two lines, it becomes sort of an oval, and it moves the margin slightly to the left

Why this happens and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a flex container so you don't need `inline-block` on the spans but flex is also the reason your long line span element is getting squashed.

A simple fix is to add `flex-shrink-0` to those spans.

Here it is working on Tailwind Play https://play.tailwindcss.com/H0kZFOVNaX

```html
<ul>
    <li class="flex items-start mb-1">
      <span class="w-4 h-4 mt-1 mr-2 bg-gray-500 rounded-full"></span>
      <a
        class="cursor-pointer"
        wire:click="changeLesson({{ $lesson }})"
        >Some regular sized content</a>
    </li>
    <li class="flex items-start mb-1">
      <span class="w-4 h-4 flex-shrink-0 mt-1 mr-2 bg-gray-500 rounded-full"></span>
      <a
        class="cursor-pointer"
        wire:click="changeLesson({{ $lesson }})"
        >Some extra large XXXL sized content that has way too long of a title and can smash an inline element.</a>
    </li> 
</ul>
```